# Cache entire data universe?

Tags: python, pandas, caching, parameter-passing

I'm working with a few large data sets that I'm looking to cache - querying from the database each time is somewhat slow and the data won't change over the course of a day so I was looking for a way to load the whole dataset once when ready and hold in memory to read from as needed. However the database calls are based on subsets of data, something like:

```
def get_db_results(pk=None, start_date=None, end_date=None):
    query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.large_table "

    if id:
        query += f"WHERE id = {pk}"
    if start_date:
        query += f"AND date >= '{start_date}'"
    if end_date:
        query += f"AND date <= '{end_date}'"

    return pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

Are there any existing libraries that would be able to infer from the cache what specific records are available base on those inputs and return just that data? Or would I need to manually pull down the data and check the in memory values for the specified set? Are there any best practices for this sort of set up?

Comment: (1) there is standard [functools.cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) to cache results from function. If you will run function with the same parameters then it will get result from cache. (2). python has standard module to work with database `SQLite` - and it can create database in memory - so you can copy data to this database and use it.

Comment: if you want to keep all dataset in memory then maybe read all as `pandas.DataFrame` and later get values from this `DataFrame`. But if dataset is too big for keep all as `pandas.DataFrame` then you may have the same problem when you will try to keep all in memory using other methods.